# Help writing a complex join query

Tags: sql, join, self-join

I am having a table orders

```
orders (
id  int unsigned not null,
fcr_date  TIMESTAMP,
completion_date TIMESTAMP,
factory_no  varchar(255),
vendor_no  varchar(255))
```

Please  ignore  the  data  type typos if any.

I want  to  write a  sql query  that helps me fetch the data  per vendor  factory.  The data  to fetch includes  the  number  of orders per vendor factory(a unique  group of vendor_no, factory_no),  vendor_no, factory_no  and  the number  of orders  for which fcr_date is  greater than completion_date.

I am new to sql  and  this particular query seems  quite  complex  to  me.  I  would appreciate if  some one could guide me thro on  how  to  write  this query.

Thanks.

Comment: ignored any typos - but you need to highlight the lines with code or table definitions and then use the "code" button (010 101) on the editor toolbar to get a nice formatting - otherwise, your posting looks awful or might even miss stuff .....

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT  vendor_no,
        factory_no,
        COUNT(1),
        SUM(CASE WHEN fcr_date > completion_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM    @orders
GROUP BY vendor_no,
        factory_no
```

Comment: Hello,
I was  wondering  if you could help me with this one. The requirement  has changed  a  bit to filter  based on  %age of orders where fcr date is greater than completion date. I wrote the following  query but  to no help.

SELECT  vendor_no As vendor,
        factory_no As factory,
        COUNT(1) as count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fcr_date > completion_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as filter_orders,
 ROUND(filter_orders / count * 100, 4) as  percent  
FROM    @orders
GROUP BY vendor_no,
        factory_no
HAVING percent>20

Postgre complains  that it  needs  a column called percent to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   vendor_no,
         factory_no,
         COUNT(id),
         SUM(IF(fcr_date > completion_date, 1, 0))
FROM     orders
GROUP BY vendor_no, factory_no;
```

Works for me with MySQL.

Comment: IF seems  like  a  part of  PL/PgSQL..  gives me syntax error in pgsql.

Answer (score 0):

Ishu, name your column as something other than 'percent' as percent might be a pgsql function!